# codeigniter 4 Undefined property: App\Controllers\Test::$load

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm switching to Condeigniter 4.
Trying to do some basic stuff.
I can't load the model into controller function.

Controller Test.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Test extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
}
```

Model User_model.php

```
<?

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class User_model extends Model
{
    public function get_user_info($user_id) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error: **Undefined property: App\Controllers\Test::$load**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter 4 and 3 have different way to load model. In codeigniter 4 you can use

```php
use CodeIgniter\Model\User_model;

$modelUser = new \App\Models\User_model();
```

or

```php
$userModel = model(User_model::class);
```

or you can see in Codeignter 4 User Guide, [Accessing Models](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html?highlight=model#id2)

Answer (score 1):

Model loading approach has been changed to **Codeigniter 4**. The way of loading the models that you use in your code has been replaced. Check out the library [Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#models) and information about loading the model can be found here [Accessing Models](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#accessing-models).

**Controller** - test code

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Test extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $TestModel = new TestModel;
    
        $this->data['test']   = $TestModel->test(2);
        
        return view('App\Views\test',$this->data);
    }
}
```

**Model** - Test code

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class TestModel extends Model
{

    public function test($var = 1)
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

The above sample code allowed us to reference the **$test** variable in the view, which will display the value **2**.